# How would one go about finding the key to this crackme (polynomial - childhood crackme)?

Tags: crackme

I'm trying to solve a crackme that contains a key check like so:

```
    lVar4 = vulnerability1(passwd);
    if (lVar4 == 0x260a4c7d7af23fc0) {
      solve_check(1,0xffffffff);
      free(passwd);
      uVar3 = 1;
    }
```

with childhood vulnerability being

```
long vulnerability1(char *param_1)

{
  char *local_20;
  long local_10;

  local_10 = 0x7364626d;
  local_20 = param_1;
  while( true ) {
    if (*local_20 == 0) break;
    local_10 = local_10 * 0x1003f + (long)(int)*local_20;
    local_20 = local_20 + 1;
  }
  return local_10;
```

}

Basically, vulnerability1 cycles through each letter of param1 and applies some transformations. It returns this transformation and it must be the value **0x260a4c7d7af23fc0**

My question is: Is there an more "correct" way of finding the correct string besides brute force? How would a veteran RE person do this?

Comment: looking at decompilation alone without accompanying disassembly is not a good practice from the looks of it a longlong needs to be returned by a long multiplied with  a const doesn't look  feasible the overflow will get lost.

Comment: Apologies, should of mentioned the architecture and os. This is 64 bit Intel, Linux. So long would be 8 bytes.